# What is considered fast performance for a single server request?

Tags: performance

I understand there are several factors involved when making db calls and internet, but i am referring strictly to the methods processing the requests, not the roundtrip to the client. I am using stopwatch to get an average range but i do not know what is generally considered fast or decent performance. 10ms 500ms?

Comment: How big is big enough?  How small is small enough?  Fast enough that your users don't leave because it's taking too long.

Comment: thats not what i mean. you are talking seconds, im interested in lower level.

Comment: More precise details would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really subjective question, but I think it is valid. All of us know that 4 MPH is slow for the car, while 150 MPH - very fast. Now lets back to servers. The fast (indexed) call to the DB takes about 20 ms. Let say we need 5 of them. Storage latency is also about a 5-10 milliseconds with data dozens of megabytes per second throughput.  Let say we need to read 1Mb. It should take let say 50 milliseconds. 10 milliseconds of CPU is enough to make dozens of searches in the various maps. 10-20 is enough to efficiently fill some template of the result.
 So we get to sum 20*5 (for DB) + 50 (file system) + 10 (in memory searches)+20 (template filling). 180 milliseconds. So very very roughly we can assume that efficient server, not overloaded, not doing excessive scans over data should have around 200 milliseconds respond time. From above we can also assume that get less then 50 - is very challenging. 
Of course all above is depends on many factors, but the goal of the post - to give some feeling what is fast and what is slow.

Comment: thanks, this is the kind of info i am trying to put into perspective.

Comment: I am working in the area of performance tuning, and think that having idea what is fast, what is slow, and what is "regular" times for many kinds of operations is essential for discovering and fixing performance problems.

Comment: @TheFrost Very simple server which translates each API to one KeyValue NoSQL request can fall into 10 millisecond range. In the same time - system doing something a bit more meaningful probably will take at least dozens of milliseconds at least...